# In Magento 2.2.5, Is possible to make default "Add Product" to be a virtual product

Tags: product, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, By Default, when we click the `Add Product` it is adding the `Simple Product`. Is possible to make it the "Add Product" to be a virtual product.